# Why isn't binary.Read() reading integers correctly?

Tags: c, struct, go

I'm trying to read a binary file in Go.

Essentially I have a struct like this:

```go
type foo struct {
    A int16
    B int32
    C [32]byte
    // and so on...
}
```

and I'm reading from the file into the struct like this:

```go
fi, err := os.Open(fname)
// error checking, defer close, etc.
var bar foo
binary.Read(fi, binary.LittleEndian, &bar)
```

Now, that *should* work, but I'm getting some weird results. For instance, when I read into the struct I should get this:

```
A: 7
B: 8105
C: // some string
```

but what I get is this:

```
A: 7
B: 531169280
C: // some correct string
```

The reason for this is because when `binary.Read()` is reading the file, after it reads the `[]byte{7, 0}` as `int16(7)` (the correct value for `A`), it comes across the slice `[]byte{0, 0, 169, 31}` and tries to convert it into an `int32`. However, `binary.Read()`'s conversion does this:

`uint32(b[0]) | uint32(b[1])<<8 | uint32(b[2])<<16 | uint32(b[3])<<24` where `b` is the byte slice.

But what really confuses me is doing the exact same thing in C works perfectly fine.

If I write this in C:

```c
int main()
{
    int fd;
    struct cool_struct {
        short int A;
        int32_t B;
        char C[32];
        // you get the picture...
    } foo;
    int sz = sizeof(struct cool_struct);
    const char* file_name = "/path/to/my/file"

    fd = open(file_name, O_RDONLY);
    // more code
    read(fd, &foo, sz);
    // print values
}
```

I get the correct results. Why is my C code getting this correct while my Go code isn't?

Comment: I recall some versions of C could write 32 bit integers in a middle-endian form. can you post a hex dump of the start of the file?

Comment: @Jasen using xxd: `0000000: 0700 0000 a91f 0000 7074 732f 3300 0000  ........pts/3...`

Comment: that changes everything,  your int16 is 4 bytes long :)

Comment: @Jasen But in Go int16 is 2 bytes long. For example: http://play.golang.org/p/u1_bBJSeSo

Comment: But the first 4 bytes of your file are for field `A`

Comment: @eric_lagergren it is in C also,  what has actually happened is the C compiler has added some padding after the int16_t  so that the int32_t can be 4-byte aligned

Comment: Further possible reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672205/packed-structs-in-gccgo

Comment: @Phylogenesis Thanks. Funny enough, I was just reading that question when my phone let me know you replied! :)

Comment: the 'C' struct definition is NOT actually working for reading the contents of the file.  For one reason, there will be 2 bytes of padding between the first and second field.  That padding will be replace with the last 2 bytes of the first four 0 bytes from the file.  There 2 bytes are not referenceable except by referencing the whole struct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the first two characters of the string aren't '\000'

what you've got there is an alignment problem, your C compiler is putting an extra two bytes of padding after the int16, Go isn't

easiest fix is probably just to add a dummy (padding) int16 after 'A'

```
type foo struct 
{
    A int16
    A_pad int16
    B int32
    C [32]byte
}
```

or the may be a way to tell go that the int32 needs to be "4-byte aligned"

if you know of one please edit this answer or post a comment

Comment: Yeah, the padding works. Go lets you use `_` for padding... somehow that didn't register when I read the docs the first time. It's a shame they don't align like C does.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @eric_lagergren Actually, the alignment is there (use `unsafe.Offsetof` to verify that). It's just that  `binary.Read()` requires you to explicitly specify alignment so your code is portable.

Answer (score 1):

```
given:

0000000: 0700 0000 a91f 0000 7074 732f 3300 0000 ........pts/3...

the fields, per the struct, are:
0700h that will be the short int field, little endian format =  7

0000a91fh that will be the  int field, little endian format = the big number
...

your struct needs a second short field to absorb the 0000h
then 
0700h = 7
0000h = 0 in new field
a91f0000 = 8105
....

which indicates (amongst other things) that the struct is missing 
the expected 2 byte padding between the short and the int fields
does the C code have #pragma pack?
```